# Avoiding stack overflow when recursively adding numbers

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have a recursive function that adds a value `number` on the first recursive call, adds `number-1` on the second recursive call, and so on until it reaches 0. I have implemented this function as:

```
public static int func(int number, int retval=0)
{
    if (number<=0)
        return retval;
    return func( number-1, retval+number );
}
```

How I can write this without creating a stack overflow when it is called with a large `number` value? Do I need a separate file?

Comment: It's not about *files* here, it's about recursion that's deep enough to exhaust the stack. Make your method iterative instead (or use language that supports tail recursion, like F# :))

Comment: Sorry please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

In the first recursive call you add `number`, in the second you add `number-1`, and so on until you finally add 0 and stop recursing. Therefore this is equivalent to just returning `retval + number + (number-1) + ... + 1`, [which is equal to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) `retval + (number+1)*number/2`.

Therefore you can avoid recursing entirely (and the potential of a stack overflow) by replacing your function with:

```
public static int func(int number, int retval=0)
{
    if (number<=0) {
        return retval;
    } else {
        return retval + (number+1)*number/2;
    }
}
```

An added benefit of this approach is that it runs in `O(1)` time, while both the recursive approach from your question and its iterative counterpart run in `O(number)` runtime.

Comment: Her homework assignment is to turn a recursive into an iterative loop.  This really isn't helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant where does it state in OP question version 1 what her assignment is?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a recursive function like yours, which does not operate on the result of the recursive call but just returns it to the caller, you can replace the recursive call with a jump to the top of the function's body with suitable parameter substitution.

For your function:

```
public static int func(int number, int retval=0)
{
    if (number<=0)
        return retval;
    return func( number-1, retval+number );
}
```

That would look like this:

```
public static int func(int number, int retval=0)
{
top:
    if (number<=0)
        return retval;
    //return func( number-1, retval+number );
    number = number - 1;
    retval = retval + number;
    goto top;
}
```

To get rid of the ugly `goto` you can substitute with a `while` loop (since the exit condition is at the top).

Now the function looks like this:

```
public static int func(int number, int retval=0)
{
  while (! number<=0)
  {
    number = number - 1;
    retval = retval + number;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

It is no longer recursive and there cannot cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

If you must use recursion add an integer to your function which contains the remaining 'space' in the stack, something like:

```
public static int func(int number, int retval=0, int numberOfCalls)
{
    if(numberOfCalls >= maximumBeforeStackOverflow)
    {
        //throw exception you can catch (you can't cath stackoverflow if i'm correct)
        //or break func
    }
    if (number<=0)
    {
        return retval;
    }
    return func( number-1, retval+number, numberOfCalls++ );
}
```